# can I configure DDWRT on 2nd router as AP so that devices connect to router with strongest signal?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point, dd-wrt

I have two routers (main and AP) with Ethernet cables connecting them.
Both routers are using the same SSID and passwords.

I want to roam around the house and have my laptop automatically switch to the router with the strongest signal (as opposed to staying locked on the router that it is first connected to).

Are there any settings in DDWRT that allow this?

Answer (score 0):

Roaming between APs within an SSID is the client's decision. The settings in DDWRT *always* allow this.

If the current signal is still of good quality, the laptop may roam *eventually* but not necessarily *immediately.* For Windows, roaming decisions are made by the specific Wi-Fi driver – e.g. Intel Wireless drivers have (or at least used to have) a ["Roaming Aggressiveness"](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005546/wireless/legacy-intel-wireless-products.html) setting.

Usually clients try to not roam needlessly, as the background scan for better APs may introduce unwanted latency every time the laptop needs to scan other channels (or at least that's my impression from seeing gamers discuss disabling it<sup>1</sup>) and the roaming procedure itself involves a disconnection and reconnection, which causes momentary packet loss – unless both APs support "Fast Transition" (802.11r) and/or "pre-authentication".

(My guess is that enabling 802.11r (which [DD-WRT does not support](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_access_point)) *may* cause clients to be more aggressive; but I'm not sure whether this has much of an effect on WPA-Personal APs, as it's WPA-Enterprise where auth can be rather slow.)

<sup>1</sup> (On that note, make sure *you* haven't disabled roaming on your laptop.)

Comment: thanks. it makes sense that the client decides to switch between AP's.  I have a newer Macbook pro and it seems that it does support 802.11r but you are saying that DD-WRT does NOT support it. is there a plan to support it?  Do you know how i configure wifi roaming on macos , im not finding anything. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using MacOS, i have found an article addressing this subject

https://jay.gooby.org/2021/01/14/make-os-x-roam-to-the-strongest-wifi-signal

note that there is an 'airport' command in macos that can be accessed from CLI

https://osxdaily.com/2007/01/18/airport-the-little-known-command-line-wireless-utility/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).